# How to integrate Phantom wallet in react project?

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, smartcontracts, solana, phantom-wallet

I actually desire to integrate phantom wallets into my custom hand website. Since I'm new to the web 3, I've just used Metamask and am unsure of what Solana and Phantom Wallets are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a provider and then wrap your _app with this provider:

```
import {
  ConnectionProvider,
  WalletProvider,
} from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react'
import { WalletModalProvider } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui'
import { PhantomWalletAdapter } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets'
import { useMemo } from 'react'


const WalletConnectionProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const endpoint = useMemo(() => 'https://api.devnet.solana.com', [])

  const wallets = useMemo(() => [new PhantomWalletAdapter()], [])

  return (
    <ConnectionProvider endpoint={endpoint}>
      <WalletProvider wallets={wallets} autoConnect>
        <WalletModalProvider>{children}</WalletModalProvider>
      </WalletProvider>
    </ConnectionProvider>
  )
}

export default WalletConnectionProvider
```

or you manually check for `window.solana` the way you connect to `window.ethereum`

```
const isWalletConnected = async () => {
    try {
      const { solana } = window;
      if (solana) {
        if (solana.isPhantom) {
          console.log("phantom wallet found");
          // When using this flag, Phantom will only connect and emit a connect event if the application is trusted. Therefore, this can be safely called on page load for new users, as they won't be bothered by a pop-up window even if they have never connected to Phantom before.
          // if user already connected, { onlyIfTrusted: true }
          const response = await solana.connect({ onlyIfTrusted: false });
          console.log(
            "public key",
            response.publicKey.toString()
          );
          setWalletAddress(response.publicKey.toString());
        } else {
          alert("Please install phantom wallet");
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```